# How to show that a hyperbola is isomorphic to a punctured line as varieties?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am studying the first chapter of Hartshorne. I want to show that the hyperbola $V(xy-1)$ is isomorphic to the punctured line. I am aware that the projection function, $(x,1/x)\rightarrow x$, is continuous and has continuous inverse. However I do not know what does a regular function on the hyperbola or the punctured line look like and how to show that the projection function is indeed an isomorphism of varieties from the definition.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\from}{\colon}\newcommand{\IA}{\mathbb{A}}\newcommand{\after}{\circ}$You want to show that $f \from V(xy-1) \to \IA^1$, $f(x,y) = x$ and $g \from \IA^1\setminus\{0\} \to V(x,y)$, $g(t) = (t, 1/t)$ are morphisms of varieties. You want to us Lemma 3.6 for this. From this lemma you can conclude:

1. In order to check that $f \from V(xy-1) \to \IA^1$ is a morphism of varities, it suffices to check that $f$ is a regular function.
2. In order to check that $g$ is a morphism of varieties, it suffices to check that $x \after g$ and $y \after g$ from $\IA^1 \setminus \{0\}$ to $\IA^1$ are regular functions on $\IA^1\setminus\{0\}$, where $x,y \from V(xy-1) \to \IA^1$ are the coordinate functions.

The first statement is immediate from the definition of *regular function* (right at the beginning of chapter 3). For the second statement, we compute $x \after g = (t \mapsto t)$ and $y \after g = (t \mapsto 1/t)$. Again, it is immediate from the definition, that these are regular functions (locally quotients of polynomials).

Note that it is not sufficient to show that $f$ is a bijective morphism of varieties: There are bijective morphisms whose inverse mapping is not a morphism of varieties. You have to make sure that both $f$ and its inverse map $g$ are morphisms of varieties.

Comment: thank you for your answer, may I ask why in the first point, you said it suffices to check f is regular?